# Adjust data types automatically when importing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV into SQL Server 2008 R2 using the import assistant.
When I follow the steps, I can see an overview of the mapping. The problem is, that per default all types are set to `varchar` and the size to `50`, regardless of the content of the columns:

[image]

In my case, there are over 100 columns with different content types (numbers, dates, long text, etc.). When I still proceed, I finally get an error message, that in some columns the text was too long, it had to be cut and as a consequence the import failed.

Is there any chance, that the assistant takes care of the data types automatically, so that I won't have to adjust every single one of them manually?

Comment: I know this doesn't directly answer your question but when I need to load a CSV file I generally use a BULK INSERT. I have never had issues with the length of fields using this method unless the field in the table I was inserting to was too small to take the data, which may be the same problem you are experiencing here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this is to convert the CSV into an Excel workbook. When SQL Server's import assistant reads Excel sheets it tries to auto detect the data type by looking at the top (some number, I don't recall) values for each field. If your data is in good shape this could just fix your problem outright.

But if you're getting errors with the CSV it's likely that you'll get errors with the Excel too, but the error messages will be more helpful in identifying which fields may be the problem (if it gives a text truncate error you'll know not to look at the number formatted fields, for example.)

Also a very common CSV import problem is delimiter values in the field data.  E.g. if the delimiter is a comma and you have free-text entry fields it's likely a user typed a comma.  An easy way to test if this is the problem, using an Excel sheet version of the file, is to use the find function to check for commas and replace them with something that's not the delimiter like an underscore.

Yet another option is to change your delimiter.  If you use the Region and Language settings in Windows you can change the "List separator" to something unlikely to exist in your data, like bars `|`.  To do that, change the setting, open the CSV in Excel and resave it as a CSV with a new filename.  Excel will use the new character as the delimiter.